# CMAKE DSO linking

Tags: linker, cmake, shared-libraries, ld

I'm totally new to cmake. After an svn update (but also to binutils and I suspect this is causing the problem), I get an error (I successfully compiled and used the program before)

```
Linking CXX executable gmsh
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/liblapack.a(dgesvd.o): undefined reference to symbol '_gfortran_concat_string@@GFORTRAN_1.0'
/usr/bin/ld: note: '_gfortran_concat_string@@GFORTRAN_1.0' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [gmsh] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/gmsh.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Maybe it's related to this [Fedoraproject DSO Change](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UnderstandingDSOLinkChange)?

I have an up-to-date archlinux (binutils-2.23-1).

I tried to edit lines in the `ccmake .` menu. After hitting [c] the original options are restored (so I cannot add `/usr/lib/libgfortran.so.3` to the `GMSH_EXTERNAL_LIBRARIES` variable in order  `[g] generate` the new Makefiles).

I also tried adding some options which were recommended in the *cmake irc chat*, but it eventually didn't work.

```
 cmake . -DCMAKE_LINK_FLAGS=-Wl,--add-needed
```

or

```
 cmake . -DCMAKE_LINK_FLAGS=-lgfortran
```

Resulting in the same error. What can I do?

Additional information: `make VERBOSE=1` [pastebin link](http://pastebin.com/xhbzasvb)

Comment: Did you try `cmake . -DCMAKE_LINK_LIBRARY_FLAG=gfortran`?

Comment: @Fraser I just tried that, but it yields the exact same error. I guess all I need to achieve is adding `-lgfortran` to the `ld` call.

Comment: This can usually be achieved by adding `gfortran` to the [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command:target_link_libraries) call in the appropriate CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @Fraser if you make this an answer I'll accept it because that worked! `target_link_libraries(gmsh ${LINK_LIBRARIES} gfortran)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add a library to the link command, you can use [`target_link_libraries`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3atarget_link_libraries).  Apparently in this case you want:

```
target_link_libraries(gmsh ${LINK_LIBRARIES} gfortran)
```